# Can't open these tabs in my Browser

Tags: javascript

I'm working with my college on a drupal website. However, we're both logged in as Admin, but I can't open these tabs.

[image]

He says he has no problem with it and told me it could be a Java problem. I reinstalled Java and checked in mutiple browsers, but I still can't open them. Do you guys have any clue why?

I run on windows 8.1, I have the latest Java and Flash installed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Java and flash ain't gonna help you here! You have javascript errors, the most common cause of that in the admin theme is using the jQuery Update module with its default settings. If you do have that module installed, just go to its config page, and select the default Drupal jQuery for the admin theme

Comment: hmm, http://puu.sh/iYBhU/01b355338a.png any specific version I should use?

Comment: I can't remember the exact text off the top of my head, but it's something like "use the one included with Drupal"

Comment: But if your collegue has no problem with these, it's unlikely that the error is caused by jquery update. Do you have some script blocker installed in your browser?

Comment: Nope, just addblock. I've set it to jquery version 1.10. It works now, but CT is gone now :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *Clive* pointed out,

> You have javascript errors, the most common cause of that in the admin
>   theme is using the jQuery Update module with its default settings. If
>   you do have that module installed, just go to its config page, and
>   select the default Drupal jQuery for the admin theme

The ***Jquery Update Module*** cause the problem. I configured the module and set my Jquery version to 1.10. This solved my problem